# how can i put the database and connection on same file

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a program I am currently trying to change from MySQL to MySQLi. The following database configuration is in one file:

```
<?php
define ("DBHOST","localhost");
define ("DBUSER","user");
define ("DBPASS","pass");
define ("DBNAME","name");


/*define ("DBUSER","root");
define ("DBPASS","");
define ("DBNAME","date_demo");*/

define ("DBPREFIX","");
define ("CHAR_SET","utf8");
define ("CACHEDIR","");
?>
```

The other section is on another page:

```
$conn = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS) or die(mysqli_connect_errno());

$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query("select * from settings where id = '1' "));
```

How can I get them all onto one page? Any ideas would be much appreciated so I can start converting to MySQLi.

Comment: copy and paste? not sure what your actully asking

Comment: If you desperately want these two on one page, I see nothing stopping you – just copy the second piece code onto the same page as the first.

Comment: theres also over 300 lines in the second page would that go over aswell hun

Comment: no one can help you unless you do a better job explaining yourself

Comment: `include` or `require`

Comment: i have my database connection split between 2 files and im wanting to put them both together as i think it would be easier to change from mysql to mysqli as ive been told to do

Comment: so um do it then- still dont see a question

Answer (score 1):

by doing this, you are borderline mixing procedural and OOP php which is highly ill advised. If you want to keep the connection seperate, you can

```
include 'conn.php';
```

however i would highly reccomend looking into building a PDO object and running any queries via that. a useful tutorial can be found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_hNNAdyfQk&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc which introduces the concepts of using global variables and shows how to instatiate a DB object which creates a better structure for your code and abstracts functions from data.

Comment: Ive tried PDO But cant get on with it :(

Comment: by using prepared statements, you give better protection from sql injectections etc. This is important if you are building a form that can retain sensitive user data. Please try the tutorial as shown above and see how you get on. The only way to learn the right way is to be thrown in the deep end.

Comment: ill give it a look and ty for your help hun

Comment: Even without using PDO, you can make prepared statements with `MySQLi`, and coming from MySQL, it is not so difficult of a transition.  However, the `include` statement shown in this answer will allow you to combine the second file with the first, so it should answer your question...